# Python - Recalculate current date

Tags: python, flask

I have a python app running in a server (using flask) and i am having problems with the current date.

I have a method that calculates current date:

```
import time
def calcCurrent():
    return(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

It works fine during this day, but, if I try to access to the server the day after and I call this method, it still returns the previous day date. It is, it doesn't recalculate current date.

Any idea on how could I do this?

Comment: Weird. If you call the function again, it should return the current date. If you used this function to define a variable, the variable won't automatically change after 24h.

Comment: Note that `return` is a statement, not a function, so the outer parentheses aren't needed.

Comment: Looks like the date has been cached...

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
import datetime

def calcCurrent():
  return(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: I did, but still returns the date when the server was started rather than current date